# How to make deeplinks clickable (working) when opening email from native app like Outlook

Tags: email, outlook, deep-linking

I was wondering if anyone had a work around to make deeplinks clickable into emails opened from a native app mail client and specifically Outlook app. 
My scenario is, i'm sending an email in which I have a CTA linking to the homepage of my app, unfortunately when open from outlook app (on my iphone & from an android) the deeplink becomes unclickable.
Any idea on how I could prevent this and make the deeplink work in each and every scenario?

Thanks so much for your support!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Horrific work around in place > I have inserted a code snippet for Outlook mail client to be redirect to a webpage with a CTA with my deep link...

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Has anyone found a solution for this? Else, can someone share info on the work around?